# extract handset name from useragent

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, user-agent

I would like to know how we can extract the `handset name` from the `user-agent` string.

For example my user-agent string is
`Mozilla/5.0 (Symbian/3; Series60/5.2 Nokia500/000.094; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, LIKE Gecko) NokiaBrowser/7.3.1.35 Mobile Safari/533.4 3gpp-gba`,then I have to extratct the result as `Nokia500`.

Since the handset id's index is differs from each user-agent I am not able to find it, how can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [user-agent-utils](http://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/) to parse the `user-agent` string and get whatever you want from it.